# Symfony2 QueryBuilder SQL to DQL

Tags: php, sql, symfony, dql, query-builder

can anybody help me converting my SQL into valid Doctrine DQL Code?

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks_done WHERE tasks_done.user_id = $userid AND tasks_done.task_id = tasks.id) = 1 AND tasks.user = $userid
```

What I tried:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $qb = $em->createQuery("
        SELECT
            t
        FROM
            tasks t
        WHERE
            t.id IN (
                SELECT
                    td
                FROM
                    TaskDone td
                WHERE
                    td.task_id = t.id
                AND
                    td.user_id = $id
            )

        AND
           t.user = $id
    ");
    $taskDone = $qb->getResult();
```

This throws following exception:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 71 near 'tasks t
>   ': Error: Class 'tasks' is not defined.

My Entites are called: Task.php and TaskDone.php , Classname is the same like filename.
Table names are: tasks and task_done

**EDIT**

Structure TaskDone.php Entite

```
<?php
```

namespace Seotool\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="task_done")
 */
class TaskDone
{


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $task_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $user_id;

/**
 * Set task_id
 *
 * @param integer $taskId
 * @return TaskDone
 */
public function setTaskId($taskId)
{
    $this->task_id = $taskId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get task_id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getTaskId()
{
    return $this->task_id;
}

/**
 * Set user_id
 *
 * @param integer $userId
 * @return TaskDone
 */
public function setUserId($userId)
{
    $this->user_id = $userId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get user_id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getUserId()
{
    return $this->user_id;
}

}
```

Structure Task.php Entitie

```
<?php

namespace Seotool\MainBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tasks")
 */
class Task {

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $task_title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $task_description;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $task_priority;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TaskTypes", inversedBy="task")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tasktype", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $TaskTypes;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="task")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $User;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set task_title
 *
 * @param string $taskTitle
 * @return Task
 */
public function setTaskTitle($taskTitle)
{
    $this->task_title = $taskTitle;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get task_title
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTaskTitle()
{
    return $this->task_title;
}

/**
 * Set task_description
 *
 * @param string $taskDescription
 * @return Task
 */
public function setTaskDescription($taskDescription)
{
    $this->task_description = $taskDescription;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get task_description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTaskDescription()
{
    return $this->task_description;
}

/**
 * Set task_priority
 *
 * @param string $taskPriority
 * @return Task
 */
public function setTaskPriority($taskPriority)
{
    $this->task_priority = $taskPriority;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get task_priority
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTaskPriority()
{
    return $this->task_priority;
}


/**
 * Set TaskTypes
 *
 * @param \Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\TaskTypes $taskTypes
 * @return Task
 */
public function setTaskTypes(\Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\TaskTypes $taskTypes = null)
{
    $this->TaskTypes = $taskTypes;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get TaskTypes
 *
 * @return \Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\TaskTypes 
 */
public function getTaskTypes()
{
    return $this->TaskTypes;
}

/**
 * Set User
 *
 * @param \Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\User $user
 * @return Task
 */
public function setUser(\Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
{
    $this->User = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get User
 *
 * @return \Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->User;
}


}
```

**EDIT 2**

Current code of my controller, which result is an empty array:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $qb = $em->createQuery("
        SELECT
            t
        FROM
            SeotoolMainBundle:Task t
        WHERE
            t.id IN (
                SELECT
                    td
                FROM
                    SeotoolMainBundle:TaskDone td
                WHERE
                    td.task_id = t.id
                AND
                    td.user_id = $id
            )

        AND
           t.User = $id
    ");
    $taskDone = $qb->getResult();
    $done = print_r($taskDone, true);
```

Table TaskDone has entries ( ID 1 | Task ID 36 | User ID 13 )
Task with ID 36 exists.

Comment: can you post the stucture for task and taskdone entities?

Comment: Hi, I've added the file contents of both entities. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your query should be more simple.

What do you want exactly? 
All of the tasks which has been done by a specific user?

So, if you join these two tables and filter on the taskDone.user, it should works.

Let's try this.

```
SELECT 
    t
FROM
    SeotoolMainBundle:Tasks t, SeotoolMainBundle:TaskDone td
WHERE
    t.id=td.task_id
AND
    td.user = $userid
```

(be careful about the names I gave to your tables, I'm not sure)

Perhaps, I did not understand what do you want. If it the case, please be more accurate ;)

Comment: You are my hero!!! It WORKS!!! :-D You cant believe how happy I am after 2 weeks of trying different ways. Now it's so simple. I'm a really beginner in Symfony and this knowledge pushes me so far in the right direction! Thank you sooooo much.

Comment: You're welcome, but after re-reading of your first query, you want: "All tasks which I've been create and realized by the same user". Is it right? If it is the case, you have to add another filter which is `AND t.user = $userid`

Comment: Do I have to? I ask because I just take all tasks , which are in taskDone AND user_id is in task done. So I think this should be enough to get all tasks which are marked as done AND are connected to a specific user

Comment: It depends on your needs. If the retrieved data satisfied you, good :)

Comment: Otherwiese I would write ...AND td.user = $userid AND t.user = $userid ??

Comment: Yes! That's it! With this code, you will retrieve only the tasks which has been created & realized by the same user. But, if you want all the tasks realized by a user, keep `td.user = $userid`. You should improve your SQL skills, you will see, it's quite simple ;)

Comment: Thank you. Normally I have not so many problems. But DQL was new for me, but now I know how to build the queries :) Thank you !

Comment: One other question. When I want to output all tasks of a user , and want to find out in the TWIG template if one of the outputtet tasks is marked as done, how could I do it? With the solution above I only can get all tasks or all tasks marked as done. You know what I mean? Example use: I want to mark a task optical as "done" with adding another color to the output.

Comment: At the moment, the query in the main answer retrieve only the tasks done by a specific user... So all of the outputted tasks should be done, no? I think it will be easier if we continue this discussion to chat.